# you must run Visual Studio in the context of an administrator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, windows-7

Allthough Visual Studio is run as an administrator, I keep getting "you must run Visual Studio in the context of an administrator" when I try to reload my web appliation that is configured to use IIS.

Any ideas or things I can check?

***I found the solution to this issue myself:***

After investigating the EventLog, I found out that my VS installation was corrupt.
Luckaly I hadn't yet installed SP1.
Installing SP1 fixed my installation, and thus the issue.

Comment: How are you running Visual Studio as Administrator? You should be right clicking the icon and selecting "Run As Administrator".

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: OMG - NO you should not be right clicking the icon and selecting "Run As Administrator" That will make it work but if you need to do this something else is wrong with your installation. Perhaps you installed IIS after you installed visual studio and are trying to run a web project? I have had that problem before. I am sure there are countless other possible reasons, but if you have to rightclick and run as admin each time you open the app it should be a clue to you that something is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

First, try this:

1-Goto C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft shared\MSEnv

2-Find the file VSLauncher.exe

3-Right click on it, select Properties, and then the Compatibility tab

4-Check the box for Run this program as an administrator

If that doesn't work, uninstall IIS and restart.  Then reinstall IIS like so:

`Start > Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off`

Deselect everything under IIS.  Reboot.  Reinstall IIS (You will not need to reboot).  Run VS 2010 as admin.  Should work then.

Comment: @JimmyV Try the IIS reinstall.  Also, make sure IIS Metabase and IIS Configuration Compatibiility is also installed.